# Help needed to nab the malware viral activity using awk

Tags: linux, editor, sed, awk, gawk

I am facing issues with my server as sometimes the malwares are adding their code at the end or start of the files. I have fixed the security loopholes to the extent of my knowledge. My hosting provider has informed that the security is adequate now, but I have become paranoid with the viral/malware activity on my site. I have a plan, but I am not well versed with Linux editors like sed or awk or gawk so help needed from your side. I can do this using my PHP knowledge but that would be very resource intensive.

Since malwares/virus add code at the start or end of the file (so that the website does not show any error), can you please let me know how to write a command which would recursively look into all .php files (I will use the help to make changes in other type of files) in parent and all sub-directories and add a particular tag at the start and end of the file, say, XXXXXX_START, and YYYYYY_END.

Then I need a script which would read all the .php files and check if the first line of the code is XXXXX_START and last line is YYYYYYY_END and create a report if any file is found to be different.

I will setup a cron to check all the files and email the report to me if any discrepancy found.

I know this is not 100% foolproof as virus may add the data after the commented lines, but this is the best option I could think of.

---

I have tried the following commands to add data at the start -

```
sed -i -r  '1i add here' *.txt
```

but this isn't recursive and it adds line to only the parent directory files.

Then I found this - 
BEGIN and END are special patterns. They are not used to match input records. Rather, they are used for supplying start-up or clean-up information to your awk script. A BEGIN rule is executed, once, before the first input record has been read. An END rule is executed, once, after all the input has been read. For example:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "Analysis of `foo'" }
     /foo/ { ++foobar }
     END   { print "`foo' appears " foobar " times." }' BBS-list
```

But unfortunately, I could not decipher anything.

Any help on above mentioned details is highly appreciated. Any other suggestions are welcomed.

Regards,

Nitin

Comment: You'd be better off generating a SHA-256 hash for each file, and keeping a record of the official hashes somewhere other than your hosting provider (a USB stick, or a laptop, or somewhere). When you need to check, you regenerate the hashes of the files on the hosting provider, and then compare what you get this time with what you have on record for last time. Any discrepancy is due to the file changing. The most likely cause is that you forgot that you updated the file and you did not change the saved hash value, but it gives you a limited number of files (one hopes) to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to modify the files (also creates backup files called .bak):

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs sed -i.bak '1iSTART_XXXX
$aEND_YYYY'
```

You could use the following shell script for checking the files:

```
for f in `find . -name "*.php" -print`
do
    START_LINE=`head -1 $f`
    END_LINE=`tail -1 $f`

    if [[ $START_LINE != "START_XXXX" ]]
    then
        echo "$f: Mismatched header!"
    fi

    if [[ $END_LINE != "END_YYYY" ]]
    then
        echo "$f: Mismatched footer!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Be careful with find in backticks. Google for "argument list too long" if you run into this error. Or just `find -name "*.php" -print | while read f; do case $(sed -n -e '1p' -e '$p' "$f") in $'START_XXXX\nEND_YYYY') continue;; esac; echo "$f: mismatch"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Use version control and/or backups; in the event of suspicious activity, zap the live site and reinstall from backups or your version control source.

Comment: We already have SVN working for us on the server thats wy we were able to restore the site back to normal. We have a post-commit code which automatically deploys the code on the server, but the issue is malware edited the files inside .svn folder as well. SVN version control is an integral part of every development company, but that does not guarantee anything. I am trying to track down the program which is editing my files, but before that I need to get my system working enough so that my business is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find . -type f | grep "txt$" | xargs sed -i -r  '1i add here'
```

Will apply that command to all files in or under the current directory.  You could probably fold the grep logic into find, but I like simple incantations.

Comment: If these are files that don't change on a regular basis, an alternative might be to just compute a checksum (md5sum, for instance) for each file, and then check that it still matches.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I like the checksum idea, but the files keep changing as we keep changing things on the site.   Can you please explain the command you have written in your answer

Comment: @Nitin: part of your release process will be to generate the checksum of the files before you upload them, or (less satisfactorily) immediately after uploading them.  If you don't have a good enough release process, now might be a good time to start implementing one.

Comment: Seriously, you are doomed if you do not use version control. Stop the press, allocate a day or two for someone to set it up and then half a day for the whole crew to learn the basics.  Probably some of your developers are already familiar with a version control system, at least enough to run "svnadmin init" and Google how to set up access controls.